# How to use case condition in switch as variable in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here `x`, `y`, `z` are integers but those are not known at start. During the running it will calculate the values of `x`, `y`, `z`. I want to use those values as case condition.

1. Is there any way to use those values in switch?
2. Instead of switch if I use if else loop, ho

```
id = 1;

switch(id){
    case x:
        //call some function
        break;
    case y:
        //call some different function
        break;
    default:
        //error
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

No, the case labels need to be compile-time integral constants.

You will need to use conditional statements instead:

```
if (id == x) {
  // ...
} else if (id == y) {
  // ...
} else if (id == z) {
  // ...
} else {
  // "default case"
}
```

Consider also that `x`, `y` and `z` may not all be distinct, so the order of the statements matters. (But the order also matters for case labels in a `switch` if you fall through any of them.)

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence because case labels must be distinct?

Comment: @alain: Yes, but their order matters, that was the point I was trying to make (poorly).

Comment: In my case the order doesn't matter. I can write case 1 in the second place.

Comment: Also, what I was trying that I have lets say 10 cases. According to the input, among them, certain number of cases will be used e.g 5 cases. And those case labels will be set accordingly. The remaining will be unused and will not be called because switch value will not call those cases.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by n.m, Kerrek SB, and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1870046/2630032), case labels need to be compile-time integral constants.
The answer of Kerrek SB shows the immediate and intuitive `if - else if`-cascade solution.
However, if you'd also like to make use of the `break`-functionality in `switch`-statements, then the following `if - if` - cascade as general pattern would apply:

```
bool isBreak = false;
if (id==x) {
    ...
    isBreak = true;
}
if (!isBreak && id==y) {
    ...
}
if (!isBreak) {
    ...
}
```

Note that with this pattern you can express - in contrast to `switch`- also situations where more than one of the `case`-statements (denoted as `if`s) match, as, e.g. when `x == y`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not supported (as pointed out by other answers). However, worse, it is not sensible and hence cannot be emulated in any way. This is because the `case`s in a `switch` are unique and their order insignificant (except in case of fall-through), so

```
switch(enum_object) {
case A: return foo<A>();
case B: return foo<B>();
default: return foo<C>();
}
```

and

```
switch(enum_object) {
default: return foo<C>();
case B: return foo<B>();
case A: return foo<A>();
}
```

gives the same code, but

```
if(id == run_time_value_A)
  return foo<A>();
if(id == run_time_value_B)
  return foo<B>();
return foo<C>();
```

is not the same as, say,

```
if(id == run_time_value_B)
  return foo<B>();
if(id == run_time_value_A)
  return foo<A>();
return foo<C>();
```

they differ if `run_time_value_B==run_time_value_A`.